# Resharper - how to import all missing namespaces?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I replaced the usage of an extension method with Find-Replace, because Resharper unfortunately could't replace it properly. Now, I have 4000 errors in the solution, and all of them are because the namespace for the new method is missing, so I'm in a desperate need of a "fix/import all missing namespaces in the solution" functionality.

Does Resharper or some other tool have such a thing or I'm going to spend the next hours going through the files, pressing ALT+ENTER?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Been there, done that.

This might be not the most elegant way, but it worked for me and took like 10 minutes on a massive project. I've used global replace tool and added `using MyApp.Domain.Required.Namespace` to the top of all files. Then used R# on all the files to cleanup namespaces: select project in Solution Explorer, hit Ctrl+Shift+R and select "Adjust namespaces".

But do a checkin/shelf/stash whatever with your version control so you can roll back. It took me a few attempts before I got R# to cleanup namespaces correctly.

Comment: How did you add the namespace to the top of all files?

Comment: Can't remember to be honest - it was a while back. I think I used notepad++ for that and some plugin with mix of regex.

Comment: I did it with replacing "using NUnit.Framework;" with "using NUnit.Framework;using MyNamespace;", then Resharper Cleanup did the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

To build on trailmax answer:

**Add line of text to beginning of multiple files and cleanup namespaces**

1. Open up Notepad++.
2. Press Ctrl+f and choose Find in Files.
3. Tick "Regular expression" AND ". matches newline"
4. In "Find what", write: (.*)
5. In "Replace with", write: YOURTEXT\r\n\1
6. In "Filters", write: *.cs (or your file ending of choosing)
7. Choose a directory (I removed obj and bin folders before this).
8. Click on "Replace in Files" (Use Sourcetree to see that everything looks fine)

> (.*) find everything (if the dot matches newline has been ticked)
>
> \r\n is the normal eol for windows
>
> \1 represents what has been matched by (.*)

9. Open up Visual studio.
10. Rebuild
11. Fix any errors
12. Then use Resharper on all the files to cleanup namespaces: select project in Solution Explorer, hit Ctrl+Shift+R and select "Adjust namespaces".